# Many Eclipse installations, or how to install many development tools on one Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

HI all,

I have Eclipse installed with PDT (PHP Development tools).
I want to program in Java and C++, do I have to download whole Eclipse JDT and Eclipse CDT again, and have separate installations, or can I install "plugins" to handle Java and C++ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can install the plugins into the same Eclipse installation. For Helios you can use the Update manager Help->Install New Software then select the Helios site and select C/C++ in Programming Lagnuages and so on. If there's something else you need you need to get the update URL and add a new site.

Comment: I install CDT on Eclipse with Java support. It worked, but when I want to create a new Project, if I select something else than "empty project" (for example "Hello world example"), Eclipse freezes. I think of going with the "easy" way of multiple installations...

Comment: I will still validate this solution, because it seems to me like the good idea, and the crash I experiment may be fixed in the future (or just caused by something on my system), even though I used the other one.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* have one eclipse with all the plugins (and perspective). But that's tedious:

- you'll have to find the plugin jars for each of the 'suites' and place it in the plugins dir. Sometimes they might not have an update site url
- some plugins cause problems, sometimes mixing certain plugins cause problems - in short, the more plugins, the more likely your environment will crash

The way I'd suggest is to have a separate eclipse installation for each task. I myself have 3, for different sort of java development (one java, one flex, one for specific project with specific plugins)

Eclipse itself is perfectly stable and capable of supporting quite a lot of plugins. However if you are unlucky to need "crappy" plugins, there the problems being.

Comment: I disagree. I use helios with JDT, CDT, PDT, PyDev, Subversion, Mercurial, Git, AnyEditTools, Counterclockwise, M2eclipse and probably some stuff I forgot and it works like a charm.

Comment: The general-purpose plugins like m2eclipse,AnyEdit, svn, git - I have them on all environments, that's not the problem. Get Flex builder and see what happens. Or any proprietary plugin (that of course hasn't been tested). And you want to limit the impact of these crap ;)